# Arduino Zero Compiling Issues for "Test-AnalogReadFast-SAM"

Tags: arduino-zero

```
#include <Streaming.h>
#include "StopWatch.h"
#include <Albert.h>
#include "avdweb_AnalogReadFast.h"

const byte adcPin = A1; 

void setup(void) 
{ Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
  Serial << "\nanalogRead_10bit us1 analogRead_12bit us2 analogReadFast_10bit us3 analogReadFast_12bit us4";
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++) testAnalogRead();
}

void testAnalogRead()
{ static Stopwatch Stopwatch(micros); 
  //delay(1000);

  stopwatch.start(); 
  int adc1 = analogRead(adcPin); // default resolution 10bit 425us on SAMD21 
  stopwatch.stop(); int t1 = stopwatch.interval;

  analogReadResolution(12); 
  stopwatch.start(); 
  int adc2 = analogRead(adcPin); // 425us on SAMD21 
  stopwatch.stop(); int t2 = stopwatch.interval;

  analogReadResolution(10);
  stopwatch.start(); 
  int adc3 = analogReadFast(adcPin); // 23us on SAMD21  
  stopwatch.stop(); int t3 = stopwatch.interval;

  analogReadResolution(12);
  stopwatch.start(); 
  int adc4 = analogReadFast(adcPin); // 24us on SAMD21 
  stopwatch.stop(); int t4 = stopwatch.interval;

  Serial << endl << adc1, t1, adc2, t2, adc3, t3, adc4, t4;
  analogReadResolution(10); // restore default
}

void loop(void) 
{  
}
```

Hi I have to run this code in the Arduino Zero. When I try to compile this code it throws the following error:

Error:

```
In file included from /Users/RAJU/Documents/Arduino/Test_AnalogReadFast_SAM/Test_AnalogReadFast_SAM.ino:2:0:
/Users/RAJU/Documents/Arduino/libraries/Streaming/Streaming.h:102:15: warning: unused parameter 'arg' [-Wunused-parameter]
 inline Print &operator <<(Print &obj, _EndLineCode arg) 

               ^
/Users/RAJU/Documents/Arduino/Test_AnalogReadFast_SAM/Test_AnalogReadFast_SAM.ino: In function 'void testAnalogRead()':
Test_AnalogReadFast_SAM:17: error: 'Stopwatch' does not name a type
 { static Stopwatch Stopwatch(micros); 
          ^
Test_AnalogReadFast_SAM:20: error: 'stopwatch' was not declared in this scope
   stopwatch.start(); 
   ^
exit status 1
'Stopwatch' does not name a type
```

Any helps are greatly appreciated

Comment: what debugging have you done? ..... did you try anything before posting the question?

Comment: it should be static StopWatch stopwatch(MICROS);

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know the type `Stopwatch`. You have a typo there. A short look into the header file (`StopWatch.h`) shows you, that it is `StopWatch` and not `Stopwatch`. You need a big W there.

Next time first try to investigate yourself. Obviously you didn't do anything before asking here. Next time try it and then, if you  cannot find the problem, then write in your question what you have tried.

---

I was able to compile the following program in my Arduino IDE for Arduino/Genuino Zero:

```
#include "StopWatch.h"

void setup() {
  static StopWatch Stopwatch(StopWatch::MICROS);
}

void loop() {
}
```

The `StopWatch` library comes from [this Github page](https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/StopWatch). It is the same, that you linked within your other language with the same code, so I assume, that you use it.

For future questions: It is better to directly provide links to all used libraries, that are not part of the Arduino IDE.

Comment: No, I tried many times. I tried StopWatch also. It throws the same error for StopWatch and Stopwatch.

Comment: For me it compiles if I also write `MICROS` instead of `micros`. If it doesn't for you, please write a minimal working example, that shows this error, with no other library included than StopWatch

Comment: Are you also using the Arduino Zero ?

Comment: Could you please send me the link for the StopWatch library that you have used? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @RajuKC: Added the compilable code and the library link to the answer

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your reply. Whenever I ran this piece of code in my Arduino Zero Sketch folder, It says " 'MICROS' is not a member of 'StopWatch".

Comment: Are you sure you have the same library, as I linked in the answer? For this library `MICROS` is defined as a part of the enum `Resolution`

Comment: Hi, I used this library from the link "https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/StopWatch "

Comment: Mhh, maybe try this: `static StopWatch Stopwatch(StopWatch::Resolution::MICROS);` . [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506750/how-do-i-use-the-enum-value-from-a-class-in-another-part-of-code#4506768) states, that this can also work, and it correctly compiles in my IDE. Also: What IDE version do you use?

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. could you please send me the zip file of the exact StopWatch library that you have used? That might be more helpful.

Comment: Just follow the link to the Github page, that I wrote in the answer. Also this is the same link, that you already send in the comments. I think we can be sure, that we refer to the same library. The IDE version may be important, because they may use different compiler versions inside.

Comment: @RajuKC, the library comes with example code .... did you even bother to try one of the examples?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I tried to run the example code in the Stopwatch library which also does not compile.

Comment: For the more information, I use the Arduino Zero 1.8.5 version